# Merge Collections on Key as Nested Objects in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Given 3 collections:

```
$links = new Collection($array_link_objects);
$images = new Collection($array_image_objects);
$combined = new Collection();
```

Merge them so the following is true:

```
$combined[$i]->link = $links[$i];
$combined[$i]->image = $images[$i];
```

Edit: It isn't often you'll have 2 arrays that you'll need to merge on the key and nest them into properties.  But if you do, this works.

Comment: Did you merge them? Also missing a `$` in the second combined.

Comment: No, I'd like to merge them, using collection functions and not nested foreach statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way it can be done.

```
$merged = combine(['link' => $links, 'image' => $image]);

public function combine($collections) {
  $merged = new Collection();
  $max = count($collections[key($collections)]);
  for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
  {
    $item = new \stdClass();
    foreach($collections as $key => $collection) {
      $item->{$key} = $collection[$i];
    }
    $merged->add($item);
  }
  return $merged;
}
```